# seconds to next highest minutes in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a column (say "duration") in the table and that column have time in seconds (say 1,387,480,419). Here , I want to find the next highest minutes for each of these time in seconds.

For Example:

```
1 sec   = 00 Min 01 Sec => 1 Min (Output)
387 sec = 06 Min 27 Sec => 7 Min (Output)
480 sec = 08 Min 00 Sec => 8 Min (Output)
419 sec = 06 Min 59 Sec => 7 Min (Output)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the CEILING method:

```
SELECT CEILING(387/60.0)
```

Will give you 7

Comment: Hope we need 60.0 and just 60??

Comment: That's needed (decimal) so the result of the division is decimal and not integer

Answer (score 3):

Mark PM has correct answer, some alternative you may like:

```
SELECT SUM((387 + 59) / 60)
```